# If $f(x,t)$ is of class $C^1$ then does $f_n(x):=\frac{f(x,t_n)-f(x,t_0)}{t_n-t_0}$ uniformly converge to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t_0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

> **Uniform convergence**
>
> Let be $X$ a topological space and $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of functions from $X$ to $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. So we say that the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly convergent to a real-valued function $f$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there  exist a $m$ such that we have
> $$
> |f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon
> $$
> for every $x\in X$ and $n\ge m$.

So I know that if $f$ is a scalar function of class $C^1$ defined in a subset $S\times I$ of $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R$ then
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f(x,t_n)-f(x,t_0)}{t_n-t_0}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t_0)
$$
for each $x\in S$ when $t_n$ converges to $t_0$. So that the sequence
$$
\partial f_n(x):=\frac{f(x,t_n)-f(x,t_0)}{t_n-t_0}
$$
point wise converges to $\partial_{t_0}f(x):=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t_0)$ but unfortunately I did not able to understand if it converges uniformly too. So could someone show to me if $\partial f_n$ converges to $\partial_{t_0}f$ uniformly, please? In particular if the statement is true then how prove it?

Comment: So you fix $(t_k)$ and $t_0?$  PS: You are using $n$ in two different ways.

Comment: @zhw. I fix $t_0$ and I assume $t_n\rightarrow t_0$.

Comment: Right, but you fix one sequence $t_k\to t_0,$ correct?

Comment: @zhw. Yes, surely.

Comment: It is true if $S$ is compact. Let $J = [a, b] \subset I$ be a compact interval containing $t_0$. Since $f_t$ is continuous on the compact set $S \times J$, $f_t$ has a modulus of continuity $\omega$ on $S \times J$. We have by the mean value theorem that for any $x \in S$,
\begin{align}
|\frac{f(x, t_n) - f(x, t_0)}{t_n - t_0} - f_t(x, t_0)| &= |f_t(x, t_0 + \theta_n(t_n - t_0)) - f_t(x, t_0)| \\
&\leq \omega(\theta_n|t_n - t_0|) \\
&\leq \omega(|t_n - t_0|) \to 0
\end{align}
independently of $x$. Thus the convergence is uniform.

Comment: @Manson Okay. However I do not precisely understand what you want means saying that $f_t$ has modulus of continuity $\omega$. So could you explain better, please?

Comment: @Mason There might trouble defining derivatives on a compact set in higher dimensions. We could assume both $S,I$ are contained in open sets $S',I'$ and $f\in C^1(S'\times I').$ Then your result follows.

Comment: @zhw Yes I am assuming that the author means $f$ is defined on some open set $U \supset S \times I$ and $f \in C^1(U)$.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity. If $X$, $Y$ are metric spaces, and $f \colon X \to Y$ is uniformly continuous, then we can define $\omega \colon [0, \infty] \to [0, \infty]$ by $$\omega(\delta) = \sup_{d(x, y) \leq \delta}d(f(x), f(y)).$$ Note $$d(x, y) \leq \delta \implies d(f(x), f(y)) \leq \omega(\delta)$$ and $$\lim_{\delta \searrow 0}\omega(\delta) = \omega(0) = 0.$$ It is just a way to repackage standard $\delta$ $\epsilon$ proof.

Comment: Oh yeah! I saw. So if you will answer I will close the question: could you do it?